# Spring -MVC , How can I return a char in Rest Controller?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to return the value of char but its giving me error for incompatible types. How can I solve this.

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/Add",method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = 
            "application/json")

public @ResponseBody
char addNewUserId (@RequestParam("Name") char name,
                      @RequestParam("Account #") char account,
                        @RequestParam("Password") char password,
                            @RequestParam("Group Name")char group){

    userId a = new userId();
    a.setName(name);
    a.setAccount(account);
    a.setPassword(password);
    a.setGroup(group);
    UserRepo.save(a);
    return "{\"result\":\"saved\"}";
}
```

Comment: You probably want to supplement "char" with "String" in your code - in the request params as well

Comment: No, its String but I'm not understanding how can I change it to char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a char because your text is a string. You should replace Char on String.

You should use char only for a single symbol (e.g. 'H' is a char).

Comment: That helps a Lot. Thanks! I know I cant return char but I wasn't sure whether I should use an array or not.

Comment: Char is used for a single symbol. Let's imagine you have the next string - "Help", if you do "Help".toCharArray() you get the array of chars ['H', 'e', 'l', 'p'], but an element of this array is Char. 'H' - Char.